# Selection of Loss Function for Weather Insurance

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions

I am using machine learning to predict agricultural yields using weather variables as inputs.  I have been thinking about what loss function to optimize.  I have been using RMSE thus far.  The insurance payouts will only be triggered if yields drop below a threshold below the mean.  However, the value of the payouts will be tied to the predicted loss so the payouts are not simply a binary outcome.  Thus, the payouts are effectively max(0, f(inputs)).  For optimization, I was wondering if there was a best criteria for this kind of situation.  Should the loss function merely be that max(0, negative deviation from mean)?